# Fetch famous people from Wikipedia API

Tags: ajax, rest, api, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to fetch people who are still alive from Wikipedia API but I haven't figured out how to do it.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418378/wikipedia-api-search-for-famous-people) which is the same as mine and as far as I understood the only way is to search for people who only have the birth_date parameter, how do I actually do that?

For instance, if I wanted to search for "Ronaldo", I should get a list of all people called Ronaldo who are still alive. The only data I care about are date of birth, name and surname, and eventually date of death if they die.

The only thing I came up with is this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=%22Ronaldo%22&format=json
```

But it doesn't do the job that I'd like it to do because it only gets the biography and link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the following query:

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription (SAMPLE(?DR) as ?DR) (SAMPLE(?RIP) as ?RIP) (SAMPLE(?image)as ?image) (SAMPLE(?article)as ?article) WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item ?label "Ronaldo"@en.  
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.  
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P569 ?DR .} # P569 : Date of birth
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P570 ?RIP .}     # P570 : Date of death
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P18 ?image .}     # P18 : image  

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
```

[Query on Wikidata.](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FDR%29%20as%20%3FDR%29%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FRIP%29%20as%20%3FRIP%29%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Fimage%29as%20%3Fimage%29%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Farticle%29as%20%3Farticle%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Ronaldo%22%40en.%20%20%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%20%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP569%20%3FDR%20.%7D%20%23%20P569%20%3A%20Date%20of%20birth%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP570%20%3FRIP%20.%7D%20%20%20%20%20%23%20P570%20%3A%20Date%20of%20death%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fimage%20.%7D%20%20%20%20%20%23%20P18%20%3A%20image%20%20%0A%09%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription)

You can add Filter on death date to see only alive people.

Comment: The person is asking how to access it from the api not from the Wikidata Query Service

Answer (score 5):

You can execute the following query here: https://query.wikidata.org/  in order to fetch the details you are interested in.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ?id ?idLabel (SAMPLE(?birth) as ?birth_date) 
 (SAMPLE(?death_date) as ?dateOfDeath)  WHERE {
?id wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
?id wdt:P569 ?birth .
OPTIONAL{?id wdt:P570 ?death_date .}
SERVICE wikibase:label { 
bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
?id rdfs:label ?idLabel .
}?id ?label "Ronaldo"@en. 
}
GROUP BY ?id ?idLabel
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [structured data query service](https://query.wikidata.org/). The generic API does not provide much in the way of filtering.