# SPARQL: Search by value endpoint

Tags: sparql

How do I query SPARQL by a particular label's value?

For instance, if I have the wikidata URI for a particular entity, how do I search by that URI in say, `owl:sameAs`

I have tried things like

```
SELECT
?item
WHERE {
 ?item owl:sameAs ?wikilink.
 FILTER(?wikilink, <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q312> )
}
LIMIT10
```

My goal is to be able to search multiple URIs at a time and return whichever of those have a result, sort of like a regex equivalent of URIs? But I can only seem to search by label as opposed to a label's value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968092/240564

Comment: @Alexan I'm not trying to query wikidata, I'm trying to find the DBPedia equivalent of a Wikidata entity by URI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something [like this](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20%3Fitem%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ312%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) --

```
SELECT ?item
WHERE
  {
    ?item owl:sameAs <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q312> 
  }
LIMIT 10
```

-- [or this](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20%3Fitem%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fitem%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Fwikilink%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%20%3Fwikilink%20%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%28%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ312%3E%20%29%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2010%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) --

```
SELECT ?item
WHERE
  {
    ?item owl:sameAs ?wikilink .
    VALUES ( ?wikilink ) 
         { ( <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q312> ) }
  }
LIMIT 10
```

[This article](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/on-the-mutually-beneficial-nature-of-dbpedia-and-wikidata-5fb2b9f22ada) is also likely to help you out.

Comment: Amazing, thanks very much; even better that I can just shove all my links into values.